# UI not updating on MutableLiveData / ObservableField of List of custom objects property change with data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, mutablelivedata, android-binding-adapter

I am generating tabs in a tablayout using ObservableField of list of objects and data binding. After a certain operation I have to update the tabs. When I trying to change the property of the list item, the UI is not updating. Below is my code.

```
val tabsList = ObservableField<List<TabModel>>(getTabsList())

// setting the data
tabsList.get()?.first { it.isSelected }?.setPrice(price)
```

I have also tried MutableLiveData, and it's also not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your databinding logic in the XML file?

Comment: Data binding logic is nothing new. I am using a binding adapter with tablayout and list of objects as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for now. Maybe it's not the efficient way, but it is working in my scenario. Below is the code.

```
val updatedTabs = tabsList.get()
// setting the data
tabsList.get()?.first { it.isSelected }?.setPrice(price)
// setting a new list
tabsList.set(updatedTabs?.toList())
```